# Incoming File Payload awareness in Google Nearby and onPayloadTransferUpdate frequency

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi-direct, google-nearby

I'm sending a file between two phones through Nearby in a very simple scenario.

The *sender* simply crafts a `Payload` of type `Payload.Type.FILE` and sends it to the *receiver*.

On the *receiver* side, I would like to know when the file transfer began (when did the receiver become aware of an incoming file). In the documentation it states about `onPayloadReceived`:

> Depending on the type of the Payload, all of the data may or may not have been received at the time of this call. Use onPayloadTransferUpdate(String, PayloadTransferUpdate) to get updates on the status of the data received.

However, `onPayloadTransferUpdate` seems to be called solely after a significant part of the file has been transfered. From what I tested, it gets called everytimes nearby received at least 2^16 bytes.

In short, I want to know if the receiver can be aware of the start of a payload transfer before any bytes of my FILE actually get sent, i.e., `update.getBytesTransferred() == 0`.

Also, why does `onPayloadTransferUpdate` get called every 2^16 Bytes? Is it always this size?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're correct that the onPayloadReceived() callback is only triggered when the first chunk has been received.

Like @Xlythe mentioned, if you want a signal for the Receiver when the transfer started on the Sender, you could send a BYTES Payload from the Sender to let the Receiver know that a FILE is upcoming.

In any case, given our current chunk size of 64k, the delay between the transfer having started and the Receiver having received the first chunk should be (again, as @Xlythe mentioned) <1 second, since the bandwidth of Bluetooth Classic is > 64KB/sec.

Is that not what you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Nearby Connections will inform you (via onPayloadTransferUpdate) as soon as the bytes have left the device, not once they're received by the remote side. So what you're seeing is expected. The delay is, at worst, ~1 second.

If that delay is unacceptable, consider sending a BYTE payload as an acknowledgement of receipt from the receiving side.

As for the size given in onPayloadTransferUpdate, that's currently the chunk size we break the file in to. Do not rely on the size as a constant, as it's not guaranteed and we do tweak it.

Comment: I was referring to the `onPayloadTransferUpdate` callback on the remote side. I believe it gets called only after the remote side received a whole chunk, is this right? There is no way for the remote side to know when a payload transfer started?

Comment: Oh, you're right. onPayloadReceived is only received after the first chunk. You can send a BYTE payload before you send the FILE payload (which would also let you send additional metadata, like file name).